# Can I override what an association method returns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In Rails, I want to override the behavior of an association. For example, by default, if `Person has_many :hats`, calling `some_person.hats` would do a simple join using `person.id` and `hat.person_id`.

I want to modify that query to include some other criteria. For example, maybe a person's collection of hats should be just the hats that are appropriate to their country.

It seems that I could do something like this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hats, :through => :country do
    # John lives in Canada, so he gets a baseball cap and a hockey helmet
    self.country.hats
  end
end
```

**Can I control what an association returns like this? If not, would a scope be the best solution?**

I know this is a silly example, but explaining the domain logic that I need this for would be way too boring for everyone here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scopes are probably your best option because they're chainable and reusable outside your association. Otherwise, you could use association extensions. Check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187357/when-to-use-association-extensions-vs-named-scopes) for more info. [Association Extensions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions)