# Method gives ActiveRecord::Relation error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have 3 models called Price, UnitPrice and Purchase. The Price and UnitPrice models have an attribute called `amount` that I'm trying to scope to and get the total sum of both combined. I created two scopes, one for the total sum of both models. The other scope is to get the `date` attribute of both model's `date` fields.

I'm trying to do this:

```
<%= number_to_currency(current_user.purchases.today.total)
```

But get the error:

```
NoMethodError in pages#home

undefined method `today' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x77f94c0>
```

My Code:

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :price
  belongs_to :unit_price

  def total
    self.price.sum(:amount) + self.unit_price.sum(:amount)
  end

  def today
    self.price.where(:date => Date.today) && self.unit_price.where(:date=> Date.today)
  end
end

class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :amount, :date
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :purchases
end

class UnitPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :amount, :date
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :purchases
end
```

What should I do?

Comment: What does it say is undefined? It's cool to include the error message when there is one :)

Comment: @DaveNewton here you go: `undefined method price for #<Class:0x44085f0>`

Comment: Did you try just "price" instead of "self.price"?

Comment: @DaveNewton  Just now I did and it gives me the error `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method today for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x58a2308>):`

Comment: Not *defining* the scopes, *inside* the scopes.

Comment: @DaveNewton I tried doing `self.price.sum/where` and `price.sum/where`. Is that what you mean? I also did Beerlingtons suggestion. I'll keep trying different things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods `total` and `today` are defined on a model object. When you call  `current_user.purchases` you associate to a relation which is `has_many` which means that in the end it's the Array. Therefore you can't call Purchase methods on it. You can do it this way:

```
  class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
    # ...
    scope :today, lambda { joins(:unit_price, :price).
                             where(:price => {:date => Date.today}, 
                                   :unit_price => { :date => Date.today }) }
    def total
        self.price.sum(:amount) + self.unit_price.sum(:amount)
    end
  end
```

And then call it like this:

```
   <%= number_to_currency(current_user.purchases.today.inject{ |sum, p| sum + p.total }) %>
```

Scope can be called on a relation.

You need to call inject since again `total` is Purchase method and the relation is Array so you need to aggregate the array. In order to keep the code clean you may want to define a `today_purchases_total` method on `User` so then you can call it like:

```
   <%= number_to_currency(current_user.today_purchases_total) %>
```

For more info about this you may refer to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes and all RoR guides in general.

Comment: I get an ArgumentError, `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` error when calling the `....purchases.today.sum(&:total)...` scope.

Comment: Probably it uses ActiveRecord's sum method. I changed it to inject -> should work now.

Comment: This still isn't working. I actually am going to change around my design and see what I can do. Appreciate all of the help though.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem may be that you're using class methods instead of instance methods. In your Purchase class, remove the `self.` before the method definitions:

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  def total
    self.price.sum(:amount) + self.unit_price.sum(:amount)
  end

  def today
    self.price.where(:date => Date.today) && self.unit_price.where(:date=> Date.today)
  end
end
```

Comment: This gives me the error `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method today for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x58a2308>):`. Never seen this type of error before. This is when I do this: `<%= number_to_currency(current_user.purchases.today.total) %>`

Comment: When you call `current_user.purchases.today`, you're not calling a method on the `Purchase` model—you're actually trying to call the `today` method on the relation `User#has_many :purchases`.  
What you want is to define an [association extension](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions) that looks something like:  
    has_many :purchases do
      def today
        // ...
      end
    end

Comment: @AlistairIsrael This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187357/when-to-use-association-extensions-vs-named-scopes states that association extension isn't used in this way. What do you say?

Comment: @Railslearner I wouldn't worry too much about how 'they' say it should be done—if it works, it works, until it doesn't work. Having said that, yes, a named scope `today` on the `Purchase` model will  be more flexible than your current approach of class-level methods (or association extensions).