# Missing FROM-clause entry for table because of nil columns?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I think I'm getting this issue because my Child Class can belong to one Parent or the other Parent but not both. Let me show you my code and then the error.

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base # my child class
  # columns = user_id, price_id and unit_price_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :price
  belongs_to :unit_price

  scope :today, lambda { joins(:unit_price, :price).
                             where(:price => { :date => Date.today },
                                   :unit_price => { :date => Date.today } ) }
  def total
    self.price.sum(:amount) + self.unit_price.sum(:amount)
  end
end
```

And than I try to do this in my view:

```
<%= number_to_currency(current_user.purchases.today.map(&:total)) %>
```

But this gives me the error:

```
PGError: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "price"
LINE 1: ...s"."price_id" WHERE "purchases"."user_id" = 3 AND "price"."d...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "purchases".* FROM "purchases" INNER JOIN "unit_prices" 
ON "unit_prices"."id" = "purchases"."unit_price_id" 
INNER JOIN "prices" ON "prices"."id" = "purchases"."price_id" 
WHERE "purchases"."user_id" = 3 AND "price"."date" = '2012-08-16' 
AND "unit_price"."date" = '2012-08-16'
```

I really don't know exactly what its saying here but have an idea which is that the price_id is nil. Is this correct? If so how do I fix this issue? Should I create two seperate purchase models called PricePurchase and UnitPricePurchase as a fix?

Let me know what you think.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tables aren't aliased and their names are in plural (`prices`, not `price` in WHERE), so perhaps this change would help:

```
where(:prices => { :date => Date.today },
                               :unit_prices => { :date => Date.today } ) }
```

Comment: Ok cool, now it gives me an `undefined method 'to_f' for []:Array`. Now I'm lost.

Comment: `current_user.purchases.today.map(&:total)` will give you array of numbers, while `number_to_currency` wants single number. Try `number_to_currency(current_user.purchases.today.map(&:total).sum)`

Comment: It seems it doesn't calculate any of the prices or unit prices so it brings back **0** as the `total`.

Comment: If I take away `number_to_currency` it brings back an empty array like: `[]`. Is it because the `total` method is wrong? **UPDATE** Yes I believe somethings wrong with my `total` method. I'll create another question if I can't figure this out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'd suggest looking into DB, at the data on which you're running your code. Rails console might be a good place to test your scopes and data. Also I've noticed the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942377/method-gives-activerecordrelation-error which describes the root problem you're solving. The way you design models' relationships raises quite a few questions. You may want to give people some insight into your domain in order to get better answers.

Comment: And by 'more domain insight' I mean things like what is the difference between UnitPrice and Price; why Prices have date attribute and Purchase doesn't; why Price and UnitPrice need to be linked to a User if Purchase already has that link; etc.