# Method brings back empty Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this class and these methods inside of it.

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :price
  belongs_to :unit_price

  scope :today, lambda { joins(:unit_price, :price).
                       where(:prices => { :date => Date.today }, 
                       :unit_prices =>  { :date => Date.today } ) }

  # not working                                 
  def total
    self.price.sum(:amount) + self.unit_price.sum(:amount)
  end
end
```

When I try to use my scope chain like this:

```
<%= current_user.purchases.today.map(&:total) %>
```

It gives me an empty Array result of `[]`. I'm really trying to do this.

```
<%= number_to_currency(current_user.purchases.today.map(&:total)) %>
```

But this doesn't work either for this error occurs.

```
undefined method `to_f' for []:Array
```

Why does it come back empty?

Thanks.

Comment: how come you are doing a `sum` on a `belongs_to` (1-relationship) association?

Comment: What about `current_user.purchases.map(&:today).map(&:total)`?

Comment: I edited my answer for your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942377/method-gives-activerecordrelation-error/11995483 - it was my bad that I put `map` instead of `sum`. Map returns array and that's why you get array.

Comment: @Max It returns the error: `undefined method 'today' for #<Purchase:0x56c6328>`

Comment: @tokland What do you mean? I don't see how that's a problem?

Comment: @LearningRoR: `sum` does an aggregate of rows, but in a belongs_to you have only one row, why are you summing then? why not simply  `self.price.amount`? `sum` is used in N-relationships.

Comment: @tokland It supposed to be that a User has purchased X amount of prices and unit_prices. I thought that `sum` would get to the `sum` amount of all of the prices and unit prices the purchases belong to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `today` scope must be reducing the resultset to zero results. That is, if `current_user` has any `purchases` in the first place. Are you sure a `Price`'s `date` is actually a `Date`? Are you sure the `:prices` association exists on `Purchase` (although I guess it would probably throw a NoMethodError there if it didn't)?

As for your `undefined method to_f for []:Array`, even if you weren't working with an empty array, you'd still be trying to cast your array as a float. You'll want to `sum` the array of prices you'll get, and pass that to `number_to_currency`:

```
number_to_currency(current_user.purchases.today.map(&:total).sum)
```

Comment: I'm looking at the database and it shows that the user does have all of its purchases. My Price and UnitPrice fields are date columns called `date` and the associations are there. Perhaps its because a Purchase cannot have both a price_id and a unit_price_id? When I try what you have above it returns 0 but just in $0.00 now.

Comment: I don't see why a `Purchase` *shouldn't* be able to have both price and unit_price IDs. I ask if you're sure the associations exist because in your `today` scope, you're querying on `:prices`, not `:price` (plural, not singular - plural suggests a `has_many` relationship, singular suggests a `belongs_to`. I only see a `belongs_to`.)

Comment: To get the `today` scope to work I did `price` and not `prices` for it. It my application design, I decided to have just one table (Purchase) to hold price and unit price instead of making two models like PricePurchase and UnitPricePurchase. Should I take that route instead?

Comment: I'm actually going to design this different now. I appreciate the help though.